# Getting data from model with custom component for Joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

So I've been trying to get data from a single item from the database using the MVC method in Joomla. I've been inspecting com_content how to do this, but I can't seem to get the id from the URL
This is my model to get the data for a single item

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// import Joomla modelitem library
jimport('joomla.application.component.modelitem');

/**
 * Issuu Model
 */
class IssuuModelItem extends JModelItem
{
        /**
         * @var string msg
         */
        protected $item;

        /**
         * Method to auto-populate the model state.
         *
         * Note. Calling getState in this method will result in recursion.
         *
         * @since   1.6
         *
         * @return void
         */
        protected function populateState()
        {
            $app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

            // Load state from the request.
            $id = $app->input->getInt('id');
            $this->setState('item.id', $id);

            $offset = $app->input->getUInt('limitstart');
            $this->setState('list.offset', $offset);

            // Load the parameters.
            $params = $app->getParams();
            $this->setState('params', $params);

            // TODO: Tune these values based on other permissions.
            $user = JFactory::getUser();

            if ((!$user->authorise('core.edit.state', 'com_issuu')) && (!$user->authorise('core.edit', 'com_issuu')))
            {
                $this->setState('filter.published', 1);
                $this->setState('filter.archived', 2);
            }

            $this->setState('filter.language', JLanguageMultilang::isEnabled());
        }

        /**
         * Returns a reference to the a Table object, always creating it.
         *
         * @param       type    The table type to instantiate
         * @param       string  A prefix for the table class name. Optional.
         * @param       array   Configuration array for model. Optional.
         * @return      JTable  A database object
         * @since       2.5
         */
        public function getTable($type = 'Item', $prefix= 'IssuuTable', $config = array()) {
            return JTable::getInstance($type,$prefix,$config);
        }
        /**
         * Get the message
         * @return string The message to be displayed to the user
         */
        public function getItem($id = null) 
        {
            $id = (!empty($id)) ? $id : (int) $this->getState('item.id');

            if(!is_array($this->item)) {
                $this->item = array();   
            }

            // Get a db connection.
            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
            // Create a new query object.
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);

            // Select all records from the user profile table where key begins with "custom.".
            // Order it by the ordering field.
            $query->select($db->quoteName(array('id', 'title', 'username', 'docname', 'docid','date', 'pages', 'description')));
            $query->from($db->quoteName('#__issuu_publications'));
            $query->where($db->quoteName('state') . ' = `1` AND ' . $db->quoteName('id') . ' = ' . $db->qouteName($id));
            $query->order('date ASC');

            // Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
            $db->setQuery($query);

            // Load the results as a list of stdClass objects (see later for more options on retrieving data).
            $this->items = $db->loadObjectList();
            return $this->items;
        }
}
```

I get a SQL error because the $id is empty.. (I removed the prefix from the table)

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY date ASC' at line 4 SQL=SELECT `id`,`title`,`username`,`docname`,`docid`,`date`,`pages`,`description` FROM `#__issuu_publications` WHERE `state` = `1` AND `id` = ORDER BY date ASC
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your `where` clause with the following:

```
$query->where($db->quoteName('state') . ' = 1 AND ' . $db->quoteName('id') . ' = ' . $db->quote((int) $id));
```

- I've removed the quotes around `1`
- replaced `$id` with `(int) $id`
- And corrected a spelling mistake on `quoteName`

Comment: Thank you, I also changed all $this->items to $this-item. But the error I have now contains "WHERE `state` = 1 AND `id` = Array".

Comment: The id=Array is caused by your $id-variable is actually an array, so investigate this. Try print_r($id) to see how your $id-variable looks.  Perhaps you can just do (int)$id[0] instead of (int)$id

Comment: you don't need to use quoteName($id), you should just use quote($id) instead - quoteName() is used for database fields, quote() for values.

Comment: and you would probably need to use quote() around date, too, when you try to order it

Comment: well... not quite. Values are always quote(), field names quoteName(). Thus, your line should be:
$query->where($db->quoteName('state') . ' = '.$db->quote('1').' AND ' . $db->quoteName('id') . ' = ' . $db->quote((int) $id));

Comment: Ok, so I kinda figured it out, I'm a big newbie when it comes to programming for Joomla. This line ($this->getState('item.id') ) retrieves the id from a menulink directly to a single item view, am I right? But the array is empty and stays empty. But how do I get the ID when someone clicks on an item in category view?